# save object associate to another object automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi i have these classes:

```
class Core < ActiveRecord::Base   

  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :image, :class_name => 'Multimedia', :foreign_key => 'image_id'   
end


class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :core, :as => :resource       
end
```

If i try do launch this:

```
a = Place.find(5)
 a.name ="a"
 a.core.image_id = 24
 a.save
```

name is saved. image_id no
i want save automatically all changes in records in relationship with place class at a.save command. is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `:autosave => true`

See section titled **One-to-many Example** for [ActiveRecord::AutosaveAssociation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html).

You'll want something like:

```
class Place
  has_one :core, :as => :resource, :autosave => true
end
```

### Disclaimer:

The `:autosave => true` should be used on the "parent" Object. It works great with `has_one` and `has_many`, but I've run into great difficulty attempting to use it on a `belongs_to`. relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the `build_association` method to do that.  For example,

```
a = Place.find(5)
a.name = "a"
a.build_core(:image_id => 24)
a.save
```

But it might only work if the place object was created before hand.